# ViewController transitions, errors not clear

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a question please.  I’m having some trouble with ViewController transitions.  My setup code is shown below:

My MainViewController is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    //..positioning code

    do {
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.startNeonSignSound()
    } catch {
        print("couldn't load sound file")
    }

    if (entranceMusicOnceBool == false) {
         audioManager.startEntranceMusic()
         entranceMusicOnceBool = true
    }
}
@IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    audioManager.stopEntranceMusic()
    audioManager.startCampaignMusic()

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameVC") as! GameViewController
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = newViewController
}
```

Then in the GameViewController:

```
var scene1: CampaignSelectScene?

//Campaign screen
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AudioManager.sharedInstance.startCampaignMusic()

    self.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    let view = self.view as! SKView

    //Restores view to default
    view.transform = origidentity

    self.view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    view.frame.size.height = screenHeight
    view.frame.size.width = screenWidth

    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {      
        scene1 = CampaignSelectScene(size: CGSize(width: 512, height: 909))
        scene1!.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    } else {
        scene1 = CampaignSelectScene(size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 667))
        scene1!.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    }

    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    // Present the scene
    scene1?.viewController = self

    view.showsFPS = true
    view.showsNodeCount = true

    let crossFade = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 1.0)
    view.presentScene(scene1!, transition: crossFade)
}


func returnToMainMenu() {

    self.scene1 = nil
    self.removeFromParent()
    self.view = nil
    self.removeGesture()

    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainViewController
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = newViewController

}
```

When I call returnToMainMenu it brings up the Main screen again; i.e. it works, but thereafter pressing start on the Main screen (a second time) and going back to GameViewController it gets stuck when I want to go further in the Game Scene. It’s as if calling the startButtonPressed twice screws it up

The errors I'm getting are "SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler"

Maybe helpful to mention that get the same errors on the first start click into the GameViewController

Any ideas?

Comment: You may benefit from using a navigation controller.

Comment: Hi, I tried a navigation controller but with the same result

Comment: Similar question here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125298     but no answer

Comment: Because your old scene is probably still alive.  What you are doing is just spawning new viewControllers.  Since you have a storyboard, use Segues to bounce between controllers

Comment: Ok, instead of all that code in startButtonPressed, it is now performSegue(withIdentifier: "CampaignSegue", sender: nil) now the error is "Warning: Attempt to present <Proj.GameViewController: code> on <Proj.MainViewController: code > whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" .. any way to get rid of this error, been looking into but no consensus

Comment: The answer (imo) is migrate everything over to SKScenes